# Is Israel less safe right now (05/2018) tha the last year?

Tags: safety, israel

I should travel to Tel-Aviv (and stay there) for a couple weeks due to work.

AFAIK it's as safe as any western country, but some people shows doubts due to the recent increase of tension with Palestine.

Has the risk of an attack from Palestine significatively increased, compared to 2017?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Questions about safety are very difficult to answer in our format, as different people have different definitions and standards and tolerances for what is safe, and violent criminal activity is anyway highly localized, and cannot be generalized for all places in a country. For some people, Israel has always been "too dangerous," and for others, nothing will ever stand in the way of a visit. Please [edit] your post to clarify. I strongly recommend you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Comment: Also, are you only going to be in Tel-Aviv, or are you interested in the relative safety levels of other parts of the country?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not sure how you expect us to quantify the "risk" of an attack. When tensions are higher, people on the fringes of society may be motivated to action. But at the same time, they may act more irrationally and be more likely to be caught beforehand, especially as you may expect the authorities to be on higher alert and to impose restrictions intended to prevent attacks. You might check with your home country's foreign ministry to see if they have issued any warnings about particular areas or activities.

Comment: Tel Aviv seems to be pretty safe most of the time, but of course you should not go to Gaza or (Israeli-occupied) West Bank which is obviously dangerous...

Comment: Thank you choster. Of course I don't expect anyone to see the future or to quantify the risk. I was hoping to know if there's a noticeable feeling of uneasiness or fear in the general population of Tel-Aviv. Or if the increased tension is a reason to be wary or just "business as usual". Sorry, I don't know how to word it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tel Aviv is currently very safe, with no attacks of any sort recently. This has been so for several years.

The future's not ours to see. Things may deteriorate at any time. The tension with Palestinians and Iran exists, but so far has no impact on most of Israel.